# PagerSlidingTabStrip implement guide

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am trying to use this library in my app:https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

I read the documents but I didn't understand anything.I have two fragments so I want to place two tabs to my app.Where do I put the viewpager xml ?

Where do I put the this code block:

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

 // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
 PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

Just main activity or all fragments and main activity ? (I have same question for viewpager xml) Can anyone explain to me how can I implement this to my app step by step ?

Ps:https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/tree/master/sample This is the example code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> step by step

I just make it for two tabs as you asked!

**0) Add the library to your build path**

**1) Create your two fragments**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);
    }
}
```

and their layouts for example can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="This is Fragment A"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**2) Create MainActivity layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3) Create your viewpager adapter**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return (position == 0)? "Tab 1" : "Tab2" ;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return 2;
    }
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return (position == 0)? new FragmentA() : new FragmentB() ;
   }
}
```

**3) Assign adapter to your viewpager and the viewpager to the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` at the MainActivity**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
         pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

         // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
         PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
         tabs.setViewPager(pager); 
    }
```

**4) Run**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this awesome guide.But I have a problem this problem in eclipse: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix  for this line:tools:context=".MainActivity" How can I fix this ?

Comment: it is not important delete `tools:context` :-)

Comment: Okay,I have one more question can you try use framelayout instead of relativelayout ? Because I have to use framelayout.

Comment: But we can't use android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" in framelayout

Comment: yes because each `ViewGroup` has its own policy to align their children in it, for example `LinearLayout` has `orientation` and RelativeLayout dose not, ListView dose not have anything, TableView has something else, you must see how that ViewGroup align its children, look at the doc.

Comment: Thank you,last question.pager.setVisibility(View.GONE); This is returning nullpointer exception.Do you know why ? I have to hide viewpager sometimes.

Comment: No, I have to see your code and logcat ask it, I or others diffidently will help you.

Comment: Hi, I m getting PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot resolved symbole. which class i have to extend?

Comment: +1 This post really helped me with the implementation of the pagersliding app. I was struggling for a bit. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can set a custom View here in place of title? I just want to replace text with text + icon. I had done it in my project but without using this lib. Now I need to use it.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi sorry right now I can not help you, if you are in hurry ask on SO may be others help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your response.

Comment: duplicated return at `return return (position == 0)? new FragmentA() : new FragmentB() ;`

Comment: @mmlooloo This example works very fine for me. Can you just give me an example of setting this layout in another fragment instead of Activity. I just want to put the whole thing into another fragment named FragmentHome. And HomeFragment will be attached to a MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout file will have tabs on the top and a ViewPager on the bottom as shown in the code snippet below:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

**Create Fragment**

create fragment [res/layout/fragment_page.xml] and copy and paste this code

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
android:text="Fragment #X"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" />
```

In PageFragment.java define the inflation logic for the fragment section of tab content:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
private int mPage;
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

// Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
// Set the associated text for the title
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
    return view;
}
```

**Implement FragmentPagerAdapter**

The next thing to do is to implement the adapter for your ViewPager which controls the order of the tab.

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}}
```

**Setup Sliding Tabs**

Finally, we need to attach our ViewPager to the SampleFragmentPagerAdapter and then configure the sliding tabs with a two step process:

In the onCreate() method of your activity, find the ViewPager and connect the adapter.

Set the ViewPager on the PagerSlidingTabStrip to connect the pager with the tabs.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    // Give the PagerSlidingTabStrip the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // Attach the view pager to the tab strip
    tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
}}
```

And this is the result

[image]

for more information , check out the following [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip)

**Good Luck**