# Load ListView inside TabHost's tab smoothly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to load a listview which gets data from a server inside a Tabhost's Tab. But everytime i switch to another tab and come back there is always a delay generating the ListView. Once the ListView is generated everything runs smoothly, bubt i would love to load the listview smoothly as well with no visible delay.

I have a method that i created, called loadStatuses(), which is called in the following places.

OnCreate and OnResumed.

```
private void loadStatuses() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            adapter.setImageKey("Status");
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see i am basically just re-creating the listview, is there away to make this much more smoother with no delay, good on memory and performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to call your `loadStatuses` at onRsumed(). just calling it at `onCreate` is sufficient.

> I am trying to load a listview which gets data from a server inside a
>   Tabhost's Tab. But everytime i switch to another tab and come back
>   there is always a delay generating the ListView. Once the ListView is
>   generated everything runs smoothly, bubt i would love to load the
>   listview smoothly as well with no visible delay.

In order to achieve that you can use `FragmentStatePageAdapter` and `setOffscreenPageLimit(Number of tabs);` to not loading your content again. you can also use `caches` to prevent from downloading again and again when user switch the tabs.

> Hi, the reason i am doing it this way is because instead of Using
>   setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) i am using the
>   navigation drawer, and using the tabhost to be able to use both the
>   navigation drawer AND tabs.
>
> For this reason i am using
>   actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)
>   instead and inside the MainActivity, which in this case is "Home" in
>   the navigation drawer i have the TabHost.
>   Can i do this without using the actionbar?

Yes, you can use [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) library. I answered step by step how to run it with:

[PagerSlidingTabStrip implement guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178838/pagerslidingtabstrip-implement-guide/26179583#26179583)

Also note [ActionBar.Tab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html) is *Deprecated since API level 21*

Comment: Yes thank you for the suggestion, i actually was able to do what i wanted with this exact same suggestion you just gave and got everything to work, the only difference was that i used PagerTabStrip instead of the PagerSlidingTabStrip. But it seems that library is prettier so i may use that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Swipable Tab view because It is a standard way . You can follow following url :

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

and load data from server in data model and then send it to adapter , so it will not load repeated when changing the tab.
Once load you can use without interruption.

If you need any further help, plz let me know.

Comment: Hi, the reason i am doing it this way is because instead of Using setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) i am using the navigation drawer, and using the tabhost to be able to use both the navigation drawer AND tabs.

Comment: For this reason i am using actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD) instead and inside the MainActivity, which in this case is "Home" in the navigation drawer i have the TabHost.

Comment: Can i do this without using the actionbar?