# android action bar with tabs 2014

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using android studio 1.0.1, and I'm trying to add some tabs to my app. I have followed [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) tutorial.

1.When I coppied `public static class TabListener` it showed me first error - I can't use static there. Why?

2.When I tried to add some tab it shows me deprecated errors on starred(**) lines

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.**setNavigationMode**(ActionBar.**NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS**);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar.**newTab**()
                       .setText(R.string.artist)
                       .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                               this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
    actionBar.**addTab**(tab);
```

Huh? So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBar tab is deprecated from api 21. use one of below approach to fix it.

1)[FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

2)[TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

3)[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

4)[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

For implementation guide about [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) see [PagerSlidingTabStrip implement guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178838/pagerslidingtabstrip-implement-guide)
if follow that guide and have a look at the example of [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) you can also use [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) for your project. Other methods are described a lot on the internet.

Comment: and which one is the best?

Comment: I like the last tow :-)

Comment: it looks too hard for me :-D, but probably I just have to get deeper into android coding, thanks

Comment: Too hard with that step by step link?

Comment: hm, which link do you think?

Comment: [PagerSlidingTabStrip implement guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178838/pagerslidingtabstrip-implement-guide)

Comment: PagerSlidingTabStrip is the only one I don't want to use

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) Site for adding tabs

Comment: At first look at that link and then you will see there's almost same solution like above. (with same deprecated values). So no, that's not the right solution

Comment: Method invocation 'actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' more... (Ctrl+F1) 'setNavigationMode(int)' is deprecated more... (Ctrl+F1), it's deprecated

Comment: are you using this this theme in your activity. Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar