# Android swipe and tabs ui - what is "best practice" and up to date?

Tags: android, swipe, android-tabs

I have used in the past often the "**Android ActionBar FragmentPagerAdapter** and **ViewPager**" which seems a little out of date - is there a newer, more advanced/better guideline/technique to do those stuff ?

Android 4.4

for example:

> ```
> private ViewPager viewPager;
> private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
> private ActionBar actionBar;
> ```

and the TabsPagerAdapter class:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    FrontEndController context;
    WearListFragment wearListFragment;
    MobileListFragment mobileListFragment;
    FavouriteListFragment favouriteListFragment;
    AdvancedControlFragment advancedControlFragment;
    ControlFragment controlFragment;
    SetupFragment setupFragment;
    StatusFragment statusFragment;

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,FrontEndController context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context =context;

        }

    // "Setup", "Advanced","Favourite","Status","Control", "Mobile", "Wear"

    @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    //Setup
                    setupFragment = new SetupFragment();
                    setupFragment.setContext(context);
                    return setupFragment;

                case 1:
                    advancedControlFragment = new AdvancedControlFragment();
                    advancedControlFragment.setContext(context);
                    return advancedControlFragment;


                case 2:
                    favouriteListFragment= new FavouriteListFragment();
                    favouriteListFragment.setContext(context,this);
                    return favouriteListFragment;


                case 3:
                    statusFragment = new StatusFragment();
                    statusFragment.setContext(context);
                    return statusFragment;

                case 4:
                    controlFragment = new ControlFragment();
                    controlFragment.setContext(context);
                    return controlFragment;


                case 5:
                    mobileListFragment = new MobileListFragment();
                    mobileListFragment.setContext(context);
                    return mobileListFragment;

                case 6:
                    wearListFragment = new WearListFragment();
                    wearListFragment.setContext(context);
                    return wearListFragment;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // get item count - equal to number of tabs
            return 7;
        }

    public WearListFragment getWearListFragment() {
        return wearListFragment;
    }

    public MobileListFragment getMobileListFragment() {
        return mobileListFragment;
    }

    public FavouriteListFragment getFavouriteListFragment() {
        return favouriteListFragment;
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you're better off by replacing the actionbar with toolbar:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

The viewpager and tabsadapter are up to date. For the tabs i recommend using the http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html instead of the 3rd party libraries avaiable. This native solution is very solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of posibilities:

Default Android tabs and viewpager:

[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Plugins (recommended):

Most famous:

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

[image]
[image]

implement guide: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178838/pagerslidingtabstrip
implement-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178838/pagerslidingtabstrip-implement-guide)

others:

[List of ViewPager plugs](https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version#4-viewpager-gallery)

Answer (score 0):

After lollipop 5.0, instead of ActionBar we mostly make use of AppCompatActivity, Toolbar..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html